# How to make e in latex?

Tags: pdf, tex-core

How to make e in latex?
Or how to make pi

[image]

Comment: Excuse me, but what do you want? Do you want to reproduce this in LaTeX, or is the question how you type "e" and "pi"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Decoration with number PI digits](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/452355/decoration-with-number-pi-digits)

Comment: Also see [How do I display pi in LaTeX like Don?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/208426/5764)

Answer (score 3):

```
$e$
$\pi$
```

Easy questions get short answers.

Comment: @Skillmon Not anymore.

Comment: If you combine them you have a `pie`.